# Use Horn formula to prove that it is possible to produce carbonic acid

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I don't know how to translate this problem to mathematical logic language. How am I supposed to came up with a Horn formula from this? I should easily be able to test it's satisfiability after that, but I'm stuck at the beginning.

---

Suppose we have the apparatuses available to perform the following chemical reactions.

$$
MgO + H_2 \rightarrow Mg + H_2O\\
C + O_2 \rightarrow CO_2\\
H_2O + CO_2 \rightarrow H_2CO_3
$$

Further, our lab has the following basic materials available: $MgO$, $H_2$, $O_2$ and $C$. Prove (by an appropriate application of the Horn formula algorithm) that under these circumstances it is possible to produce $H_2CO_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

You have already the "basic ingredients"; you have only to formalize them as [Horn-clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) :

*Clauses*

1) $\lnot MgO \lor \lnot H_2 \lor Mg $

2) $\lnot MgO \lor \lnot H_2 \lor H_2O$

3) $\lnot C \lor \lnot O_2 \lor CO_2$

4) $\lnot H_2O \lor \lnot CO_2 \lor H_2CO_3$

*Facts*

5) $MgO, H_2, O_2, C$.

*Goal*

> $H_2CO_3$.

Now you can easily check themfor *satisfiability*.

Comment: The OP needs maybe to understand that the second clause for example comes from the conversion of  $(p \land q) \to r $ into $\lnot (p \land q) \lor r $ then into $\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r $